# how to give common path for files in bash scripts in linux

Tags: python, linux, bash

My script is like this, i want to use variables for path in order to change it anytime.How do i use $path and $storage variables for changing it anything.Actually i am taking the data from rrd files to xml files and want to parse it in python.So, please correct me

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello ak"
path= /var/lib/ganglia/rrds/cluster1/ankit21
storage_path= /home/ankit/rrd-xml

rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/bytes_in.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/bytes_in.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/bytes_out.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/bytes_out.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/cpu_aidle.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/cpu_aidle.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/cpu_idle.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/cpu_idle.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/cpu_num.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/cpu_num.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/cpu_system.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/cpu_system.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/cpu_user.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/cpu_user.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/cpu_wio.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/cpu_wio.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/disk_free.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/disk_free.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/disk_total.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/disk_total.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/load_fifteen.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/load_fifteen.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/load_one.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/load_one.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/mem_buffers.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/mem_buffers.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/mem_cached.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    >$storage_path/mem_cached.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/mem_free.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/mem_free.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/mem_shared.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/mem_shared.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/mem_total.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/mem_total.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/pkts_in.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/pkts_in.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/pkts_out.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/pkts_out.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/proc_run.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/proc_run.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/proc_total.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    >$storage_path/proc_total.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/swap_free.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/swap_free.xml
rrdtool xport -s -25m DEF:xx=$path/swap_total.rrd:sum:AVERAGE XPORT:xx:    > $storage_path/swap_total.xml

python $storage_path/zget.py


And the errors are ...
 hello ak
./zscript.sh: line 4: /var/lib/ganglia/rrds/cluster1/ankit21: Is a directory
./zscript.sh: line 5: /home/ankit/rrd-xml: Is a directory
ERROR: opening '/bytes_in.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/bytes_out.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/cpu_aidle.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/cpu_idle.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/cpu_num.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/cpu_system.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/cpu_user.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/cpu_wio.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/disk_free.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/disk_total.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/load_fifteen.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/load_one.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/mem_buffers.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/mem_cached.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/mem_free.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/mem_shared.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/mem_total.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/pkts_in.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/pkts_out.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/proc_run.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/proc_total.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/swap_free.rrd': No such file or directory
ERROR: opening '/swap_total.rrd': No such file or directory
python: can't open file '/zget.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: path= /var/lib/ganglia/rrds/cluster1/ankit21
storage_path= /home/ankit/rrd-xml  
There is a space in both the places after equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the error is in the line

```
path= /var/lib/ganglia/rrds/cluster1/ankit21
```

I think the problem is the space....

Also, try enclosing in quotes.

path="/tmp/test"

[This](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) be some interesting reading.

Comment: OPs code contains `path= /var/lib/ganglia/rrds/cluster1/ankit21` That looks like space to me too. Owen, you've probably been downvoted because it is considered better to quote the relevant parts of the provided link in your answer, rather than expect people to dig around in a remote site with a different format etc. (you can still provide the link for the super interested ;-).  Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks.  I have attempted to update the response.  Hopefully that will make everyone happy.

Comment: space was the problem.  Thanks for the help.